# Boolean algebra - Converting DNF form to CNF form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I´ve tried at least dozen ways to convert DNF to CNF, yet I always end up with something  wrong. Here is the DNF: (B ∧ D) ∨ (C ∧ D) ∨ (¬D ∧ ¬B) ∨ (¬D ∧ ¬C) .

Is there someone who can help me with it ?

Answer (score 2):

Question already answered here [Boolean algebra - Converting DNF form to CNF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377022/boolean-algebra-converting-dnf-form-to-cnf)
avoid posting duplicate questions or asking for your homework

Comment: Yes I know about this one, but it's not the same like mine.

Comment: @AlZiSVK No, not exactly the same ... but at the start of my Answer there, I give  several examples of how to use Distribution, and from those examples you can certainly figure out how it works in your case as well.